# submit button will empty the values of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="a" class="inp">
    <input type="text" name="b" class="inp">
    <input type="text" name="c" class="inp">
    <input type="text" name="d" class="inp">
    <input type="submit" name="e" class="inp">
</form>
```

---

```
$("input").focusin(function () {
     $("input").not($(this)).not(':input[type=submit]').val("");
});
```

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/PJLQq/1/

This code will clean the post values when i press the submit button. How can be solved? I only want to clean the values when the user change the focus in the user interface, not when the form is submitted.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: @A.Wolff, use firebug, or something to see the Post.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xJs4H/1/

Comment: do you want to keep the values but empty only the UI when focused...

Comment: or like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xJs4H/3/

Comment: @user455318 which one first or second

Comment: @ArunPJohny The first is exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments

```
$("input:not([type=submit])").focusin(function () {
    $("input").not(this).not('[type=submit]').val("");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xJs4H/)